# Actualizar elemento de un array

Tags: javascript, json

Para añadir es

> .push();

para borrar:

> .splice (index, 1);

pero para actualizar, para hacer un update?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para actualizar le asignas el valor al indice del array que deseas actualizar:

```js
var nombres = ['CAROLINA', 'MARIA'];

console.log(nombres);

nombres[0] = 'BERTA';

console.log(nombres);
```

En el ejemplo se actualiza el valor del indice 0 de **CAROLINA** a **BERTA**

Answer (score 7):

**[`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/splice)** también sirve para actualizar arrays. Y puede ser útil por ejemplo si queremos conocer los elementos que fueron sustituidos.

Veamos este ejemplo, en el orden de los meses olvidamos que después de Abril iba Mayo:

```js
var months = ['Ene', 'Feb', 'March', 'April', 'June'];
/* Actualizar el elemento en el índice 4*/
var removeJune=months.splice(4, 1, 'May');
console.log(months);
console.log(removeJune);
```

Hemos sustituido `June` por `May` en el array, y en `removeJune` tenemos el elemento que fue cambiado, por si necesitamos pasarlo a otro sitio o lo que sea.

También podría ser útil si queremos *regularizar* la situación del array de meses, aplicando lo que dice la documentación:

> ```
> array.splice(start[, deleteCount[, item1[, item2[, ...]]]])
> ```
>
> **`deleteCount`** | Optional
>
> Un entero indicando el número de elementos a eliminar del array antiguo. Si `deleteCount` se omite, o si su valor
>   es mayor que `arr.length - start` (esto significa, si es mayor que el
>   número de elementos restantes del array, comenzando desde `start`),
>   entonces todos los elementos desde `start` hasta el final del array
>   serán eliminados.
>   **Si `deleteCount` es igual a `0` o negativo, no se eliminará ningún elemento**. En este caso, se debe especificar al menos un nuevo
>   elemento.

Aquí agregará `May` en la posición 4 del array y no borrará a `June`, y `addMay` será un array vacío:

```js
var months = ['Ene', 'Feb', 'March', 'April', 'June'];
/* Actualizar el elemento en el índice 4*/
var addMay=months.splice(4, 0, 'May');
console.log(months);
console.log(addMay);
```

En conclusión, `splice()` no sirve **sólo** para borrar. Sirve para **actualizar** y para **insertar** elementos en el array, según la forma en que se use.